# Array sorting test

Tags: java, sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean sorted=true;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the length of your array then enter the elements of your array: ");
    int length=scan.nextInt();
    int[] array=new int[length];
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        array[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i=0;i<length-1;i++){
        if (array[i]>array[i+1]){
            sorted=false;
        }
    }
    if (sorted=true){
        System.out.println("The list is already sorted");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The list is not sorted");
    }

}
```

I have to write a program that checks to see if an array is sorted or not for class. This is my current code. I can't figure out why the code wont go into the if statement int the second for loop even though the conditions are true.

the test date I used for entry was: 8 10 1 5 16 61 9 11 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with the loop, but the last if condition:

```
 if (sorted = true)
```

should be

```
 if (sorted == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is entering the loop. The problem is below:

```
if (sorted=true){ // <-- here
        System.out.println("The list is already sorted");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The list is not sorted");
    }
```

the `sorted=true` doesn't check if the `sorted` is `true`, it actually sets it to `true` every time. Use `sorted==true` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do this changes:

```
for (int i=0;i<length-1;i++){
    if (array[i]>array[i+1] && sorted) { //you don't need loop all array
        sorted=false;
    }
}

if (sorted==true) { //sorted == true for comparison
    System.out.println("The list is already sorted");
}
else {
    System.out.println("The list is not sorted");
}
```